# Using Facebook App Links, How would i link a user from my website to my mobile app?

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

Using Facebook App Links, How would i link a user from my website to my mobile app?

I've been trying to do it but i'm unable to do so.

I've tried adding meta-tags to my html test document, using pinterest as an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="Pinterest://">
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.pinterest">
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="pinterest">
    <meta property="al:web:url"
          content="http://applinks.org/documentation" />
</head>
<body>
 Hello, world!
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a `HTML` developer. However for iOS, if you are expecting a redirection to App, then the solution would be to use `URL types`.

You can define a URL type in your iOS app by following steps -

```
1. Select your project
2. Select Target
3. Select Info Tab
4. Expand URL types option
5. Under URL schemes, specify your app URL. It can be any string.
```

Also in your Apps `AppDelegate`, you should implement either one of the following delegate methods and return `true`

`application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool`

or

`application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool`

Inside your HTML page, specify your redirect URL.

For eg. - If you specified your URL types as **`appName`** in your info list, then the redirect URL will be **`appName://`**

You can find more info [here](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html)

Comment: This used to be a great option. Unfortunately with the introduction of Universal Links in iOS 9+, URL schemes are no longer a complete solution and will result in ugly errors being shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook App Links only work if the source app is configured to support them. In an ideal world, the source app would scrape the destination URL when opening it and automatically launch the appropriate app. Unfortunately not many app are set up to do this — even the main Facebook app on iOS doesn't anymore, and Safari never did (and probably never will).

Setting up a custom URL scheme for your app and then linking directly to it does work, but in iOS 9+, the user will be shown a confirmation message first. And if the app isn't installed, there will be an ugly error message instead. [Universal Links](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9) on iOS 9+ are designed to solve this, but they aren't supported everywhere yet and can be turned off.

The solution is to use a combination of URL schemes and Universal Links:

1. You want to enable your website for Universal Links so that when a user opens a link to your website, they go directly into the app instead on iOS 9+.
2. And then have a URL scheme redirect that fires for anyone not on iOS 9. You'll probably want to put this behind a button or a link so that users without the app won't be immediately shown an error when loading the page.

This is the approach we take at [Branch.io](https://branch.io), and is fairly close to our free [deepviews](https://dev.branch.io/features/deepviews/overview/) feature. Check it out...might save a bunch of work!